VBA search through rows in spreadsheet
I'm new to VBA. I need to use one spreadsheet to look for data in another one.
Starting with baby steps, I've written the code below to step through the rows of column 3 of the first spreadsheet, find the data I'm looking for and print out the row number it's found on as well as column 13 of that row.
Sub SearchTextInRow()
Dim sheet As Worksheet
ChangedCount = 0
Set sheet = ActiveSheet

For iR = 1 To 100
    If sheet.Cells(iR, 3).Value = "Deleted" Then
        ChangedCount = ChangedCount + 1
        Debug.Print iR
        Debug.Print sheet.Cells(iR, 13).Value
    End If
Next iR

MsgBox ChangedCount

End Sub
The data in column 13 I then want to use to search through a sheet called "Equipment" in another file. So I need to open the 2nd file and do a similar For loop to find what I'm looking for.
Workbooks.Open "C:\file1.xlsx"
ActiveSheet.Name = Equipment

This is where I'm getting stuck. How do I reference this new file and sheet to then iterate through it like I had done before ?

Dim wb As Workbook, Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\file1.xlsx"). Btw, consider using Range.Find and maybe Range.FindNext instead of looping.

On a side note I'd generally avoid using ActiveSheet as it may not always be the sheet you're intending to use.  Use ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") to reference the sheet with the tab name "Sheet1" in the workbook containing the VBA code.  To reference the sheet in the other workbook, and using the code in @BigBen comment use wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").

Is there a single/unique occurrence of the search string?

Thanks very much. The line Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\file1.xlsx") causes the error Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error. The path to my file is definitely correct. What am I doing wrong ?

Could that file already be open? (I don't know if that would cause that particular error anyway.)
